# How do I raise an exception in Observable NestJS?

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

Started using NestJS and ran into a problem, how can I throw an exception inside Observable?

```
public getGuild(guildId: string, token: string): Observable<Guild | undefined> {
  const guild = this.httpService
    .get<Guild[]>(url, {
      headers: { authorization: token },
    })
    .pipe(map((result) => result.data.find((guild) => guild.id === guildId)));

  return guild;
}
```

The response that comes from the external API can be undefined, how do I check it correctly and if it is undefined make NestJS respond with a 404 code?

If you simply return this response in the controller, NestJS returns code 200, even if the response was undefined.

*I've never encountered RxJS before, so I couldn't solve this problem. The HttpModule documentation also doesn't say anything about this.*

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(guild)`? You should see something like Observable { _isScalar: false }. It will never be undefined because `guild` is a reference to your observable and not a reference to the return value(s) of your observable.

Comment: @MrkSef yes, I made a mistake in the text, it won't be undefined, it will be Observable<Guild | undefined>. I need to handle undefined inside Observable and return HttpException.

Comment: @MrkSef I corrected the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to throw an exception from within the observable, you can do something like this

```js
return this.httpService
  .get(url, options)
  .pipe(
    map(response => response.data),
    map(data => {
      if (data === undefined) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
      }
      return data;
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Was it that easy? Anyway, thank you, you saved my day. Can you recommend useful resources for learning RxJS?

Comment: [learnrxjs.io](https://learnrxjs.io) has been a huge help to me

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an error at any point in your stream. The following snippet will throw an error if `results.data` doesn't contain a Guild with the passed in `guildId`. Now your result will either be defined (Not null/undefined), or an error;

```
public getGuild(guildId: string, token: string): Observable<Guild> {
  return this.httpService.get<Guild[]>(url, {
    headers: { authorization: token },
  }).pipe(
    map(result => 
      result.data.find(guild => guild.id === guildId)
    ),
    tap(guild => {
      if(guild == null) throw new Error(`No guild with ${guildId} found`);
    })
  );
}
```

## Idiomatic RxJS

`tap` takes a stream and returns the same stream unaltered. It can be seen as the same as `map(x => x)` - Some people believe idiomatic RxJS should preclude `tap` from having any control-flow in a program.

Where this often makes sense are in situations where users are tempted to set a global variable and then make a choice based on that value later.

```
from(something).pipe(
  tap(x => {
    if(x < 10) this.globalValue = 0;
    if(x > 9) this.globalValue = 25;
    else this.globalValue = 75;
  }),
  mergeMap(x => this.service.save(x, this.globalValue))
);
```

In this case, your stream is no longer 'pure' as you can't concretely reason about what `this.globalValue` will be (Perhaps some other block of code alters this global value again before you read it). This makes things hard to test. You lose much of the benefits of RxJS functional style.

All these problems are the same if you replace `tap(x => doSomething)` with `map(x => {doSomething; return x})` - they're the same set of issues. However, idiomatically, a programmer may spend more time understanding what `map` is doing because they may expect `tap` to have no control flow.

---

#### The subjective part

In my view, `tap` is a **great** place to throw an error. It should tell any developer reading/updating the code that "this error is produced by the shape of the value at this point in the stream". Things like validation and logging fit very well (idiomatically) into RxJS' `tap` operator. Throwing an error during validation is fairly natural.

How would you write a custom assertion operator (You could strip them all for production builds without worrying that you're ruining anything)

```
function assert<T>(fn: (x: T) => boolean): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>{
  return s => s.pipe(
    tap(val => {
      if(!fn(val)) throw new Error("Assertion Failed");
    })
  );
}
```

An implementation using `tap` is a clear standout for clarity. You also don't run into any idiomatic problems during use since the word `tap` doesn't appear in your stream.

```
public getGuild(guildId: string, token: string): Observable<Guild> {
  return this.httpService.get<Guild[]>(url, {
    headers: { authorization: token },
  }).pipe(
    map(result => 
      result.data.find(guild => guild.id === guildId)
    ),
    assert(result => result != null)
  );
}
```

That's pretty clear, I'd say. We could work on a better error message though.

---

#### Another way to avoid the debate

If you'd rather not use `tap` that way, here's another way to write it in fairly idiomatically correct RxJS.

```
public getGuild(guildId: string, token: string): Observable<Guild> {
  return this.httpService.get<Guild[]>(url, {
    headers: { authorization: token },
  }).pipe(
    map(result => {
      const guild = result.data.find(guild => guild.id === guildId);
      if(guild == null) throw new Error(`No guild with ${guildId} found`);
      return guild;
    })
  );
}
```

Now - the error is thrown as a "I failed to map result: Guild[] to guild: Guild" error.

Comment: Generally, [`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) shouldn't be used for throwing errors. Mainly it should just be used for introspection

Comment: `map(val => {doSomething; return map})` - is litterally just a verbose way of saying `tap(val => doSomething)` - I've updated my answer with what might be a better approach.